# How do I make text appear using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I created a code through Codecademy. Whenever I wanted text to appear, I was told to use `console.log` However, when I actually run the code, using HTML (as a js file would not run), the text does not appear, as the console is not displayed.
The code was for one of those classic choose-your-adventure text-based games. After answering a prompt, text with the story line is supposed to appear as another prompt appears. The prompts run through, but the story line is not displayed. What could I change `console.log` to in order to make the text appear?

~EDIT~ Thank you, Vince.
I suppose some of you  did not exactly understand what I was asking.
I shared my reason for my ignorance. I learned JavaScript through Codecademy. They did not teach you how to make text appear. All they said was you could use `console.log` to make text appear. It makes text appear in the console, but I wanted it to appear outside of the console.
I went back to my script and changed every `console.log` to `document.writeln`. My code now works.
And to whoever suggested that I would be afraid of JavaScript: I wrote a lengthy and complex code for a beginner. I did not post it on here as it is my intellectual property and I did not need to post it to ask my question. I had a misconception and I wanted to clear it up.

Comment: Well there are a ton of different ways to see the text. You could open your console (`cmd` + `opt` + `J` on mac) and view it there, use `alert()`, write it to the page, etc...

Comment: console.log will only work in a js file. What exactly are you looking to print in the console?

Comment: Do you want text to appear on the actual page or in the console?

Comment: Just display the console, hit `F12` or `CTRL+SHIFT+J` in Windows machines.

Answer (score 1):

Though essentially considered bad practice, (but as a beginner you're more than welcome to use this) you can use `document.writeln('Hello, World!');` to actually write text onto the page.

You can also, in your HTML, define a container with an id:

```
<div id="my-text-box">
</div>
```

and in your JavaScript,

```
window.onload = function(){
    document.getElementById('my-text-box').innerHTML = "Hello, World!";
};
```

Comment: `document.write(ln)` is a pro method, please don't advice beginners to use it.

Comment: Whaaaat? That was literally the first thing I learned in JavaScript, though that was ages ago...

Comment: How much troubles you got with it ; )? It is purposed to write _document content_ to another document or to create a whole new document, in very rare cases it's suitable for debugging.

Comment: Hmm. I suppose you have a point.. I hope OP posts his findings instead of being permanently scared of JS.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what you want to achieve, but I guess you want to display text on your webpage. You can do this like this:

```
window.onload = function() {
var a = 'Text to be displayed'; //<<< The text you want to display
var b = document.createElement('div'); //<<< create a Element
b.innerHTML = a; // <<< append content to the element
document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(b);  //<<< append the element to the pages body
}
```